# How can I use groovy to connect to Lucidworks Fusion (solr wrapper) API?

Tags: groovy, solr, lucidworks

I have started working with Lucidworks [Fusion](https://lucidworks.com/products/fusion/) (2.1.2) and am most comfortable hacking with [Groovy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Groovy_%28programming_language%29). Side note: python 'requests' handled this seamlessly, but I am stubborn and don't want to use python...

Fusion has promising [API](https://doc.lucidworks.com/fusion/2.1/REST-API-Reference.html) which I look forward to working with in Groovy.

How do I best connect to the Fusion authenticated API in Fusion using Groovy (in a groovy-ish manner)?

I have tried several approaches (and finally found a few than worked). I welcome feedback on why the basic [RESTClient](https://github.com/jgritman/httpbuilder/wiki/RESTClient) doesn't work for me, along with other 'simple' solutions.

Here is what I tried:

```
groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder hb = new HTTPBuilder(FUSION_API_BASE)
hb.auth.basic(user, pass)
```

That fails with a 401 unauthorized (because of encoding I believe). HTTPBuilder came from gradle:

```
compile 'org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder:http-builder:0.7.1'
```

I also tried:

```
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
List <NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList <NameValuePair>();
nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", "sean"));
nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "mypass"));
httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps));
CloseableHttpResponse response2 = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
```

and got:

```
{"code":"unauthorized"}
```

Also tried:

```
String path = '/api/apollo/introspect'
URL url = new URL('http', 'corp', 8764, path)
try {
    def foo = url.getContent()
    log.info "Foo: $foo"
} catch (IOException ioe){
    log.warn "IO ERR: $ioe"
}
```

which threw (a now expected) IOError: 401. If anyone wants more info on my failures let me know and I can likely bore you with voluminous technical details.

I am shamelessly answering my own question (below) but hope that some groovy sensei out there can enlighten me a bit.

So to recap: is there a better/groovier solution than what I found below?

Answer (score 0):

So I asked the question and am posting the solution(s) I found. Hopefully folks will add better solutions and maybe even explain what I missed in my initial attempts.

Here is my preferred solution (*all three solutions below are from googling but I lost the links, feel free to poke me and I will dig them up--kudos to original posters*):

```
String furl = "${FUSION_API_BASE}${path}" //http://localhost:8764/api/apollo/introspect
RESTClient rc = new RESTClient(furl)
rc.headers['Authorization'] = 'Basic ' + "$user:$pass".bytes.encodeBase64()
//rc.headers['Authorization'] = 'Basic ' + "$user:$pass".getBytes('iso-8859-1').encodeBase64()
def foo = rc.get([:])
log.info "Foo: $foo"
```

And another working solution:

```
RESTClient rest = new RESTClient( 'http://localhost:8764/' )
HttpClient client = rest.client
client.addRequestInterceptor(new HttpRequestInterceptor() {
    void process(HttpRequest httpRequest, HttpContext httpContext) {
        httpRequest.addHeader('Authorization', 'Basic ' + 'sean:mypass'.bytes.encodeBase64().toString())
    }
})
def resp = rest.get( path : path)
assert resp.status == 200  // HTTP response code; 404 means not found, etc.
println resp.getData()
```

And for those keeping score at home, a python solution for comparison:

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
rsp = requests.get('http://corp:8764/api/apollo/introspect', auth=HTTPBasicAuth('sean', 'lucid4pass'))
print "Response ok/status code: %s/%s", rsp.ok, rsp.status_code
print "Response content: %s", rsp.content
```

HTH,

Sean